macOS App Asset Validation Failed: Invalid Code Signing and Architecture Issues
I am trying to submit my macOS app to the App Store, but I am encountering multiple asset validation errors. Below are the issues:

Code Signing Errors (90284): Many files in my app bundle, including executables, frameworks, and .dylib files, fail validation with the message:
Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'path/to/file' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.


I have ensured that the main app is signed, but the errors persist for subcomponents.

Architecture Compatibility (90869):
Invalid bundle. The “MyApp.app” bundle supports arm64 but not Intel-based Mac computers. Your build must include the x86_64 architecture to support Intel-based Mac computers.


My app only supports Apple Silicon, but the error suggests I also need to support Intel.

Sandboxing Issues (90296):
App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement.


The error lists multiple files in the app bundle.

Missing Icon (90236):
Missing required icon. The application bundle does not contain an icon in ICNS format.






What I’ve Tried:

Used codesign to sign the app and its components:
codesign --deep --force --options runtime --sign "Developer ID Application" path/to/MyApp.app



Verified the provisioning profile and certificate.

Ensured entitlements for the sandbox are set in Entitlements.plist.



Questions:

How do I ensure all executables, frameworks, and dynamic libraries are properly signed?

Can I submit an Apple Silicon-only app without Intel x86_64 support? If not, how can I include it?

How can I resolve the sandboxing errors for helper apps and frameworks?

What are the requirements for the app icon to pass validation?


